# How do you fabricate objects with has_many associations that can be queried in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fabrication-gem

I have this schema that I want to test in rspec.

```
class Question
  has_many :choices
end

class Choice
  belongs_to :question
  validates_presence_of :question
end
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
Fabricator(:question) do
  text { sequence(:text) { |i| "my question#{i}" } }
  choices(count: 2) { Fabricate(:choice, question: question)}
end
```

Nor this:

```
Fabricator(:question) do
  text { sequence(:text) { |i| "my question#{i}" } }

  before_save do |question|
    choices(count: 2) { Fabricate(:choice, question: question)}
  end
end
```

The problem I'm having is if I construct the fabrication like this:

```
Fabricator(:question) do 
  text "question"
end
question = Fabricate(:question)
choice_a = Fabricate(:choice, question: question)
choice_b = Fabricate(:choice, question: question)
(question.choices == nil)  #this is true
```

In my rspec I need to query question.choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use the shorthand in this instance.

```
Fabricator(:question) do
  choices(count: 2)
end
```

Fabrication will automatically build out the correct association tree and let ActiveRecord do its thing under the hood to associate them in the database. The object you get back from that call should be fully persisted and queryable.

If you needed to override values in choices you could do it like this.

```
Fabricator(:question) do
  choices(count: 2) do
    # Specify a nil question here because ActiveRecord will fill it in for you when it saves the whole tree.
    Fabricate(:choice, question: nil, text: 'some alternate text')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Paul.  I tried your second example, however I get an error because I have a validates_presence_of :question in the Choices class and i get a ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:Validation failed: Question can't be blank.  Do you know how I can work around this?

Comment: Validating belongs_to relationships tends to be tricky territory in general. You could change it to validate presence of `question_id` instead of `question`, which might get you through the day but may also impact the way those validations are surfaced. If it's there simply for data integrity and not to produce a validation error on screen then I would recommend removing that entirely and making sure the field in the database is `not null` and has a foreign key.

Comment: If neither of those are options, then you'll have to handle this in an after_create.

`Fabricator(:question) do
  after_create do |question| # this will be the actual question ActiveRecord object
    2.times do
      Fabricate(:choice, question: question, text: 'some alternate text')
    end
  end
end`

<-- sorry for that mess. This is too much for a comment it seems.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this Paul.  The validate presence was only for data integrity so I went with your suggestion to changing the database column so that the field is not null and adding a foreign key constraint and that cleared up the problem.  muchas gracias!